# How to retrieve the location of user which set by Geofire in real-time firebase by determining their format(double or string)?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, encryption, geofire

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GeoQueryEventListener, OnLoadLocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private Marker currentUser;
private DatabaseReference myLocationRef;
private GeoFire geoFire;
private List<LatLng> dangerousArea;
private OnLoadLocationListener listener;

private DatabaseReference MyCity;
private DatabaseReference location;
private Location lastLocation;
private GeoQuery geoQuery;
private LocationManager locationManager;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
private String userID;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private String userName;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());


    //init
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    Dexter.withContext(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

            buildLocationRequest();
            buildLocationCallback();
            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapsActivity.this);
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


            initArea();
            settingGeoFire();


        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "You must enable permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 101);



        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {

        }
    }).check();


}



private void initArea() {

    MyCity = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DangerousArea").child("dangerousArea");


    listener = this;


    MyCity.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            //update dangerous area list
            List<MyLatLng> latLngList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot locationSnapShot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                MyLatLng latLng = locationSnapShot.getValue(MyLatLng.class);
                latLngList.add(latLng);
            }
            listener.onLoadLocationSuccess(latLngList);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });




}

private void addUserMarker() {
    geoFire.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
            if (currentUser != null) currentUser.remove();
            currentUser = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude())).title("You"));

            //move camera
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentUser.getPosition(), 17.0f));

        }
    });
}

private void settingGeoFire() {
    String firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    myLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User_Location/"+firebaseAuth);
    myLocationRef.child("userID").setValue(firebaseAuth);
    geoFire = new GeoFire(myLocationRef);

}


private void getLocationFromFirebaseAndEncrypt(){

    String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    location = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User_Location").child(userID).child("You").child("l");

    location.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Double d1 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue();
                    Double d2 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue();

                    String latitude = String.valueOf(d1);
                    String longitude = String.valueOf(d2);

                    Log.d("LatLong", latitude + ", " + longitude); //Check the values


                    //encrypt
                    LocationEncryption locationEncryption = new LocationEncryption();
                    String encryptedLatitude = null;
                    String encryptedLongitude = null;

                    encryptedLatitude = locationEncryption.encrypt(latitude);
                    encryptedLongitude = locationEncryption.encrypt(longitude);

                    uploadDataToFirebase(location, encryptedLatitude, encryptedLongitude);

                    Log.d("Encrypted", encryptedLatitude + ", " + encryptedLongitude); //Check the values








                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }


    });

}

private void uploadDataToFirebase(DatabaseReference location, String encryptedLatitude, String encryptedLongitude) {

    EncryptedData encryptedData = new EncryptedData(encryptedLatitude, encryptedLongitude);
    location.child("0").setValue(encryptedLatitude);
    location.child("1").setValue(encryptedLongitude);


}


private void getDataFromFirestore(){
    //get data from firestore

    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(userID);
    documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                userName = documentSnapshot.getString("user_Name");
                Log.d("userName", "userName is "+userName);
                String firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
                myLocationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User_Location/"+firebaseAuth);
                myLocationRef.child("user_Name").setValue(userName);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Record not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Failed to fetch data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}


private void buildLocationCallback() {
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (mMap != null) {

                lastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();

                addUserMarker();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void buildLocationRequest() {
    //if(fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10f);
    // }
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 101);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            //We need background permission
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Your location can be tracked background.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                    //We show a dialog and ask for permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 102);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 102);
                }
            }

        }


    }

    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

    //add circle for dangerous area
    addCircleArea();
    getLocationFromFirebaseAndEncrypt();
    getDataFromFirestore();

}

private void addCircleArea() {
    if(geoQuery != null){
        geoQuery.removeGeoQueryEventListener(this);
        geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    }

    for(LatLng latLng : dangerousArea){
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(100).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.rgb(255,200,200)).strokeWidth(1.0f));

        //create GeoQuery when user in dangerous area
        geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 0.1f);
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(MapsActivity.this);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    //fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    sendNotification("Warning", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area, leave now! ", key));
}



@Override
public void onKeyExited(String key) {
    sendNotification("Warning", String.format("%s leave the dangerous area ", key));

}

@Override
public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    sendNotification("Warning", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area, leave now! ", key));

}

@Override
public void onGeoQueryReady() {

}

@Override
public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {

    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+content, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "geofence_multiple_location";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

        //config
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel Description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setContentTitle(title).setContentText(content).setAutoCancel(false).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    Notification notification = builder.build() ;
    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);
}

@Override
public void onLoadLocationSuccess(List<MyLatLng> latLngs) {
    dangerousArea =  new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyLatLng myLatLng: latLngs){
        LatLng convert = new LatLng(myLatLng.getLatitude(), myLatLng.getLongitude());
        dangerousArea.add(convert);
    }

    //after dangerous area have data, call map
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

    //clear map and add again
    if (mMap != null){
        mMap.clear();
        //add user marker
        addUserMarker();



        //add circle of dangerous area
        addCircleArea();

    }

}

@Override
public void onLoadLocationFailed(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //We have the permission

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                return;
            }
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Access Granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //We do not have the permission..
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Permission required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;

        }
    }

    if (requestCode == 102) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //We have the permission
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your location can be access in background.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //We do not have the permission..
            Toast.makeText(this, "Background location access is necessary.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I change the type of latitude of longitude from double to string because the encryption can only encrypt a string.
After running the code, the encrypted location (latitude and longitude) was uploaded successfully to real-time firebase. The image below shows the updated real-time firebase:
[image: updated real-time firebase with encrypted location]

From the image, the uploaded latitude and longitude are wrong. The correct encrypted latitude and longitude should be:

```
0: ipIfexJXPD3aYk6yAhS08w== and 1: YXNZe0XGx32sg6x3MKqHzA==
```

And without \n.

Although the encrypted data was successfully uploaded to real-time firebase, the application crashed. The error is as follow:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at assignment.yeo.location.MapsActivity$4.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:243)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: assignment.yeo.location, PID: 13953
java.lang.AssertionError: Got Datasnapshot without location with key You
    at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.childChanged(GeoQuery.java:284)
    at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery.access$100(GeoQuery.java:41)
    at com.firebase.geofire.GeoQuery$1.onChildChanged(GeoQuery.java:69)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:82)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

From the error above, line 243, which is specified in the error message, is:

```
Double d1 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue();
```

The latitude and longitude set by the Geofire will always change on the firebase when the user is moving. So, the application aims to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the user (when the user is static or moving) from real-time firebase and encrypt the latitude and longitude and upload them back to the real-time firebase ('0' and '1').

I hope you can understand my question. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: The issue is that your encrypting the data into a string and trying to retrieve the encrypted string as a double instead of decrypting it first then casting it to a double, which is why you get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`.

Comment: You can remove the "\n" from the strings using `string.replace("\n","");`.

Comment: Actually, the '0' and '1' represented the latitude and longitude of a user. So when the user moves, the value of 0 and 1 will also change.  I assume that the encrypted latitude and longitude will be updated with new latitude and longitude when the user is moving. So I can retrieve them and encrypt them again and upload them back to real-time firebase. Is that any solution for this? Hope you can understand what I m trying to say.

Comment: The decryption will not be processed here

Comment: Possibly, as soon as you send the encrypted location back your `onDataChanged` would immediately run again and it would read the encrypted data and crash in the way I mentioned earlier. One possible solution is to filter the data(determine if it is a valid location) before you use the value, which may be done by checking if `dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue()` is a double and not a string before proceeding.

Comment: If you know Node.js, and are willing to learn to use the following tool, you can look at using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=Cj0KCQiAtJeNBhCVARIsANJUJ2FT_1uM02DEwzEJ37QQ_-TD-5Eu_uVtZK1DsU1m85QFamXMNThJxE4aApxjEALw_wcB) to handle encrypting your data instead of encrypting on client-side.

Comment: I have tried to used  if(dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue() == double.class && dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue() == double.class) to determine if the data(latitude and longitude) store in firebase is valid or not (double) before retrieving the data. But when I used this method, the latitude and longitude cannot be retrieved and encrypt.

Comment: I have updated the code above. Hope you can take a look at it! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239720/discussion-between-zi-zian-yeo-and-alias-cartellano).

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I will try first and if I will update it later！！！Sorry about that！

Comment: Thanks, the encrypted latitude and longitude can update continuously to firebase for now and i have updated the code above. But the uploaded latitude and longitude still have the '\n'. The "\n" will automatically add to the latitude and longitude when I upload both of them to firebase!

Comment: Maybe I can remove it when i want to retrieve the latitude and longitude from the firebase and decrypt it?

Comment: You can use the replace method I mentioned earlier of you wish to do that.

Comment: Hi, the code was being updated. The problem appeared again although I have used try and catch. Can you please take a look at the code? Thank you.

Comment: The error message was also updated. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is the cause of your error:[Got datasnapshot without location](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java/issues/140#issuecomment-457903911)

Comment: Is that the current stacktrace and code? Did you remove the try catch?

Comment: @AliasCartellano yes. this is the current stack trace and code that i currently used. If I remove the try-catch, an error will occur at encryptedLatitude = locationEncryption.encrypt(latitude) and show Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception which required try-catch to solve.

Comment: The value of 'g' and 'I' in the firebase is automatically set by geofire in my code. So, I think that the solution of 'Got datasnapshot without location' that you provided cannot solve the problem because it required me to insert the value of 'g' and 'I" manually. I will update the code to contain the geofire part of my code.

Comment: @AliasCartellano Is it because of the code cannot convert the encrypted location stored in the firebase as a string into double 'Double d1 = (Double) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue();'. When I remove the function 'getLocationFromFirebaseAndEncrypt(), the entire code run smoothly without error.

Comment: Try skipping the `(double)` conversion using `String latitude= dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue().toString();
                    String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue().toString();` and omit `d1` and `d2`.

Comment: It still cannot be solved. An error "java.lang.AssertionError: Got Datasnapshot without location with key You" occurs after i use ur suggestion. Maybe I just upload my whole class in this question and could you please take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: I used geofence in my application. Everything is ok when the user's location is outside the geofence (red circle on the map), but when the user's location is inside the geofence, the app crash. I m not sure how to solve it. I have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your `GeoQuery` issue, since your old problem is solved I suggest you open up another question with the aforementioned issue so that others can see. Is it possible to omit the `GeoQuery` code if that solves the problem?